# A function to get users to block and report each other in a social media app

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I'm just a beginner to coding and android app development and after I uploaded my app on google play it was removed by google by the reason of not having reporting a user, content and also blocking them and I've been stuck with this problem for weeks and I wasn't able to find a solution for it if anyone have an idea of what to do I'll be very happy

I tried making a db reference for the blockingref and tried to make the amount of data it retrieve from the users as less as I could and made a simple function but it didn't work and I don't know what to do so I deleted all that and tried to start from the beginning but I didn't reach to a solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. Can you show us some code?